# Replacing N/A from VLOOKUP using IFERROR

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm trying to change any N/A's I receive when using VLOOKUP to blanks. This is currently the formula that I am using to run the VLOOKUP.

```
Sheets("WSO Interest").Range("H" & i).FORMULA = _
"=VLOOKUP('WSO Interest'!G" & i & ",'WSO Positions'!G:H, 2, 0)"
```

I am not sure where to put the iferror statement and this is a formula that I am working with but I keep getting an error stating that the object is not defined.

```
IF iserror('WSO Interest'!G" & i & ",'WSO Positions'!G:H, 2, 0)
range(H)=""
else: ('WSO Interest'!G" & i & ",'WSO Positions'!G:H, 2, 0)
end if
```

Any ideas? All help is appreciated!

Comment: `Sheets("WSO Interest").Range("H" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),"""")"`

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, just use:

```
Sheets("WSO Interest").Range("H" & i).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),"""")"
```